# Excel VBA - Color of Range Changed when I paste the value from Different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm having a weird problem. I try to copy and paste values only from different sheet to different sheet. However when i try to paste the values, the color change at the targeted cells. Below are the pictures before and after paste.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image]

If i delete the values, it become as the first picture. Below is the code i used to copy the values:

```
Sub TP1Pas()

Sheets("SUMS").Range("B29:F48").Copy
Sheets("Summary").Range("B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Hope you guys can help me for this.

Comment: Conditional formatting?

Comment: Care to explain more @Comintern? Thanks

Comment: Do the cells in column B of the "Summary" sheet have any conditional formatting?

Comment: Thanks @Comintern, i get now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some background conditional formating active in your excel sheet. Check Home > Conditional formatting > Manage Rules to check if there are any existing rules.

Comment: hi @tEddy, yea i got it. The previous commenter helped me. thanks